# Is Symfony built in server concurrent?

Tags: symfony

I am wondering can Symfony built-in server handle more than one request at the same time?

```
php bin/console server:run
```

Comment: As far as I know it can only handle one request at the same time. It's just intended for local development.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/32pfw0/using_phps_built_in_server_in_production/ The Symfony server is just a thin wrapper over the php server.